# ASP.NET CorrelationManager.ActivityId is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, nlog, trace

I'm using NLog version 4.5.2, and I'm trying to use the `${activityid}` LayoutRenderer.
I've followed the instructions at the NLog tutorial page: [NLog ActivityId](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Trace-Activity-Id-Layout-Renderer)

As mentioned, I instantiated the `System.Diagnostics.Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId` by setting: `System.Diagnostics.Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId = Guid.NewGuid()` at the `Application_BeginRequest` event.

Loally it worked great, but after I deployed it to a different server, I've noticed that the `${activityid}` isn't written.

After some searching and debugging, I came across a weird situation.
At the line of code in the `Application_BeginRequest` event, the `ActivityId` is set just right, but then when the real http post method occurs, I see that the `ActivityId` has the value of an empty guid (0000-00...).

One thing I've noticed it, that the ActivityId is emtpy when sending POST request with data on the request (Again - only to the remote server).

Can someone help me out with this issue?
I can't seem to figure it out.

**UPDATE #1:**

I checked the same version of my application on Windows Server 2012 and it worked (My problem is currently on Windows Server 2008 R2).

**UPDATE #2:**

I couldn't find a solution for why this is happening only on Windows Server 2008 R2 and not locally (Windows 7) or on Windows Server 2012, but I managed to find a workaround/different solution.

Instead of instantiating the `System.Diagnostics.Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId` in the Global.asax.cs class, at the `Application_BeginRequest` event, I created a new `DelegatingHandler` and instantiated the `System.Diagnostics.Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId` at the SendAsync method of the `DelegatingHandler`

In this scenario, the `ActivityId` is generated for each http request (as same) but now it isn't empty when the request is a HTTP POST request with data inside.

An example is found here [DelegatingHandler Example](https://github.com/jonwagner/EventSourceProxy/issues/24)

Comment: Having the exact same issue C#/asp.net/iis/nlog but running asp.net MVC. Have you learned anything new that might help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Yes. The solution for my issue is described in Updae #2 which was the thing that solved my problem. Of course I wanted it to be solved naturally but it was a real long ago and I don’t think it could happen naturally in my case.

Comment: Unfortunately, it’s not possible to do the same thing for MVC. That said I found out that the app pool on the WS 2008 box was set to enable 32-bit applications which is not the default. When this setting is set to false the problem goes away. Would be interested in that solves the problem for you as well.

Comment: Might be. Unfortunately I’m not developing on the same team so can’t check that out :(

Comment: Ok nw. Thanks for getting back to me. Was a tricky one for sure.

Comment: Yes. I’m not sure if i tried the 32bit solution back at the time but the other problem was that the application used 32bit dependencies so it was switched on

Comment: That’s the same situation I’m in. We technically need it turned on. That said it going to dig deeper now that I know this is causing our problem to see what options we have.